# Streaming Audio Record in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, audio

To build an interactive app I want to integrate record audio streaming with my react native app. I hunted through

- [react-native-audio-streamer](https://github.com/indiecastfm/react-native-audio-streamer),
- [react-native-sound-recorder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sound-recorder) and
- [react-native-audio](https://github.com/jsierles/react-native-audio)

But I didn't find an acquiescent API for this purpose. Is there any package or manual method to accomplish?

Comment: By interactive app do you mean speech to text?

Comment: @Kranthi exactly for that purpose.

Comment: react-native-voice for listening and react-native-tts for text to speech

Comment: @Kranthi Thank you. This should be for English, we have our own engine for tts and I need such tools in Persian.

Comment: @AtiBarzideh are you trying to record audio streams, instead of voice? Did you manage to do it?

Comment: @ChrisEdwards Thanks for your comment. Yes I'm trying to record audio and then send it to my server in order to create an app which represents the proper text continuously simultaneously. The point is making live speech to text feasibility.

Comment: Ah ok! I’m trying to record audio from a network stream, but failing miserably :-/

Comment: @AtiBarzideh Did you find a solution? I am also searching for it but cant find it. I dont want to eject expo..

Answer (score 2):

Try `react-native-live-audio-stream` link is [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-live-audio-stream)